# Getting the product id in the database

Tags: php

I want to get the product id in the database and then add a quantity when i press the add button to the product. The code is working but it only get the

```
<?php

global $con;
$ip = getIp();
```

=
                +"; ?>

```
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: why r u using post and get together, when u need id from get than why just use this <a href='cart.php?pro_id=<?=$pro_id?>'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is completely wrong, you should check how to create forms in html. A button should not be inside of a link. You should add hidden input.